# How to count the number of times a number comes up?

Tags: java

Im making a code for class where you roll a pair of dice x amount of times. I got the loop and values working, but I'm not sure how to go on and actually count how many times a sum is repeated (2-12). I was looking online and saw that an array could help, but nowhere in the directions does it mention anything about an array. Im still a very new cs student so I am not 100 percent familiar with everything. Thank you.

Comment: You give too little information for us to be able to help you. Please read [ask] then [edit] your question to add some details about a specific problem you need help with.

Comment: With that said, step away from your computer and think about how you would solve this by hand. Let's say you have a die, paper, and pencil. You roll the die and then what do you do to keep track of the counts for each number? Try to describe this as clearly as you can in plain English.

Comment: I would use the pencil to write down a list on the paper of all the sums I get. After that I just go down the list and count the amount of times I get a specific number. I would then write down the sum and how many times it came up. I would repeat this process for all 100 rolls.

Comment: You can use a hashmap to pair up each number with a frequency, but it sounds like you want to use an array. You can create an array of integers of size 11 (2-12 is 11 numbers). Each time a particular number occurs, you can increment the index for that number. Being that you're dealing with 2-12, you would need to offset the index by 2, `freq_array[current_dice_roll -2] += 1`

Comment: @Carlos That's a good start! So start with the first step "write down a list on the paper of all the sums I get". Try to figure out how you would store that list of sums in an array.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an array(or hashmap) to store the count of the number of times the sum is repeated(2- 12). Here is the solution using an array:

***Solution using Array:***

int[] diceSum = new int[12];

1. index -> 2 - 12 denotes the sum of the dices (can ignore 0,1 index)
2. diceSum[index] = frequency [ tells the frequency/count of each sum ]

Every-time user throw Dice, put the frequency in index position. If it is zero, put one or otherwise increment the old value by 1.

### **diceSum[index] = diceSum[index] + 1;**

> *Function*:
>
> *throwDice() -> throwing a pair of dice which return's sum (M+N)*

```
int[] diceSum = new int[12]; //by default all index have value 0's

for(int j = 0; j < numberOfThrows; j++){
    int sum = throwDice(); // throwDice returns number between 2-12
    diceSum[index] = diceSum[index] + 1; //increment the count for each sum
}

return diceSum;


throwDice() -> returns (2,3) -> 2 + 3 = 5;   -->  diceSum[5] = 1;
throwDice() -> returns (2,3) -> 3 + 4 = 7;   -->  diceSum[7] = 1;
throwDice() -> returns (2,3) -> 2 + 8 = 10;   --> diceSum[10] = 1;
throwDice() -> returns (2,3) -> 4 + 1 = 5;   -->  diceSum[5] = 2;
throwDice() -> returns (2,3) -> 6 + 6 = 5;   -->  diceSum[12] = 1;
throwDice() -> returns (2,3) -> 4 + 8 = 5;   -->  diceSum[12] = 2;
```

***Solution using HashMap:***

Similarly, 2-12 can be considered as key in the hashMap and value can be the frequency for the sum. Solution is given below :

```
Map<Integer,Integer> map = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();

for(int diceSum = 2; diceSum <= 12; diceSum++){
     map.put(diceSum, 0);
}

for(int j = 0; j < numberOfThrows; j++){
    int sum = throwDice(); // throwDice returns number between 2-12
    map.put(sum, map.get(sum) + 1); //increment the count for each sum
}

return map;
```

Hope this helps.